# javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException:imap and javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException:pop3

Tags: jakarta-mail, obfuscation

I create an Android email reader app using JavaMail, before obfuscation, it works fine. However obfuscation messes up the app and throws the errors "javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException:imap and javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException:pop3"

The proguard cfg file content is:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-verbose

-libraryjars "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar"

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn java.beans.Beans
-dontwarn javax.security.**

-keeppackagenames javax.mail.**
-keeppackagenames javax.activation.**
-keeppackagenames com.sun.mail.**
-keeppackagenames myjava.**
-keeppackagenames org.apache.harmony.**
-keeppackagenames mailcap.**
-keeppackagenames mimetypes.**

-keep class javamail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.imap.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.pop3.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.dsn.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.util.** {*;}
-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}

-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }  
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.sun.activation.registries.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }  
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.**  
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

Please advise what went wrong, thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I created "referenced libraries" in Eclipse, move all .jar files from "lib" folder to "referenced libraries" folder. It WORKS now.